I am trying to automate a Flutter app using Flutter Finder, but I am getting "unknown locator" for each and every Flutter element
I am trying to automate flutter app using java and flutter finder but I am getting unknown locator for each and every flutter element. Here I am attaching java code. Please let me know what is the problem here.
public class FlutterAutomation {

    private static AndroidDriver driver;
    private static final String appPath = "C:\\Users\\NMAHESHBABU\\flutterlogin-debug.apk";
    private final String deviceName = "Pixel 3 API 29";
    private final String testName = "Flutter Automation";
    
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities flutterCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        flutterCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
        flutterCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        flutterCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "flutter");
        flutterCapabilities.setCapability("app", appPath);
        flutterCapabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
        flutterCapabilities.setCapability("testName", testName);
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), flutterCapabilities);
        System.out.println("Created AppiumDriver");
    }

    @Test
    public void checkLoginFunction() throws Exception {
        FlutterFinder find = new FlutterFinder(driver);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        FlutterElement txt_username = find.byValueKey("txt_username"); // this is valid locator
        FlutterElement txt_password = find.byValueKey("txt_pass"); // this is not a valid locator actual locator is txt_password
        FlutterElement btn_click = find.byValueKey("button_login");// this is valid locator
        System.out.println(txt_username);
        System.out.println(txt_password);
        
        txt_username.sendKeys("user@gmail.com");
        txt_password.sendKeys("user123");
        btn_click.click();
    }
    

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}

Output:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Created AppiumDriver
[io.github.ashwith.flutter.FlutterElement@6cfedde -> unknown locator]
[io.github.ashwith.flutter.FlutterElement@8343364 -> unknown locator]
FAILED: checkLoginFunction
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '4.13.0', revision: 'ba948ece5b*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [f457e47b-31f2-4c5c-af08-1f94839dbe02, sendKeysToElement [id, value]]
Capabilities {appium:address: 127.0.0.1, appium:allowCors: false, appium:allowInsecure: [], appium:androidCoverage: false, appium:app: C:\Users\NMAHESHBABU\flutte..., appium:appWaitActivity: false, appium:appWaitPackage: false, appium:automationName: flutter, appium:backendRetries: 3, appium:basePath: /wd/hub, appium:bootstrapPort: 4724, appium:debugLogSpacing: false, appium:defaultCapabilities: {}, appium:defaultCommandTimeout: 60, appium:defaultDevice: false, appium:denyInsecure: [], appium:deviceName: Pixel 3 API 29, appium:deviceReadyTimeout: 5, appium:dontStopAppOnReset: false, appium:enforceStrictCaps: false, appium:fastReset: false, appium:forceIpad: false, appium:forceIphone: false, appium:fullReset: false, appium:intentAction: android.intent.action.MAIN, appium:intentCategory: android.intent.category.LAU..., appium:intentFlags: 0x10200000, appium:isolateSimDevice: false, appium:keepArtifacts: false, appium:keepKeyChains: false, appium:keyAlias: androiddebugkey, appium:keyPassword: android, appium:keystorePassword: android, appium:keystorePath: C:\Users\NMAHESHBABU.andro..., appium:launch: false, appium:launchTimeout: 90000, appium:localTimezone: false, appium:localizableStringsDir: en.lproj, appium:logNoColors: false, appium:logTimestamp: false, appium:loglevel: debug, appium:longStacktrace: false, appium:nativeInstrumentsLib: false, appium:noPermsCheck: false, appium:noReset: true, appium:port: 4723, appium:reboot: false, appium:relaxedSecurityEnabled: true, appium:robotAddress: 0.0.0.0, appium:robotPort: -1, appium:safari: false, appium:sessionOverride: false, appium:shell: false, appium:showConfig: false, appium:showIOSLog: false, appium:skipUninstall: true, appium:suppressKillServer: false, appium:testName: Flutter Automation, appium:tmpDir: C:\Users\NMAHES~1\AppData\L..., appium:useKeystore: false, appium:wdaLocalPort: 8100, appium:webkitDebugProxyPort: 27753, platformName: ANDROID}
Element: [io.github.ashwith.flutter.FlutterElement@8343364 -> unknown locator]
Session ID: f457e47b-31f2-4c5c-af08-1f94839dbe02
txt_username is valid locator but i am getting unknown locator [io.github.ashwith.flutter.FlutterElement@6cfedde -> unknown locator]
for txt_password is not a valid locator but I am getting [io.github.ashwith.flutter.FlutterElement@8343364 -> unknown locator]
Pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>PracticeTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>PracticeTest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.ashwithpoojary98</groupId>
            <artifactId>appium_flutterfinder_java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>


